# Can I set and animate the opacity of multiple entities with one animation?

Tags: aframe

I've got an entity with some plane that I'd love to set up like so:

```
<a-entity id="ui" opacity="0" position="0 -10 0">
  <a-plane class="menu-pane" position="0 0 -60" opacity="0" color="blue" rotation="0 0 0" height="50" width="30"></a-plane>
  <a-plane class="menu-pane" position="50 0 -40" opacity="0" color="blue" rotation="0 -50 0" height="50" width="30"></a-plane>
  <a-plane class="menu-pane" position="-50 0 -40" opacity="0" color="blue" rotation="0 50 0" height="50" width="30"></a-plane>
  <a-animation begin="mobileMenuOpen"  attribute="position" dur="550" fill="both" to="0 0 0"></a-animation>
  <a-animation begin="mobileMenuOpen"  attribute="opacity"  dur="550" fill="both" to="1"></a-animation>
</a-entity>
```

So I could emit the `mobileMenuOpen` event on `#ui` and have the entity and all its planes fade in and move up. However, `opacity="0"` on `#ui` doesn't affect the child elements, and I'm not sure if the animation will either. How can I achieve my desired effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in animation framework can't apply to multiple entities, and (afaik) setting the opacity of a parent doesn't cascade down to it's children. What I would do is to make your own version of the `opacity` component, which does apply itself to children. Let's call it `group-opacity`. This is a naive version (and might not work for models exported from a modeling tool), but –

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('group-opacity', {
  schema: {opacity: {default: 1.0}},
  update: function () {
    var opacity = this.data.opacity;
    var children = [].slice.call(this.el.children);
    children
      .filter(function (child) { return child.hasAttribute('opacity'); })
      .forEach(function (child) {
        child.setAttribute('opacity', opacity);
      });
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<a-entity id="ui" group-opacity="opacity: 0" position="0 -10 0">
  <a-plane class="menu-pane" position="0 0 -60" opacity="0" color="blue" rotation="0 0 0" height="50" width="30"></a-plane>
  <a-plane class="menu-pane" position="50 0 -40" opacity="0" color="blue" rotation="0 -50 0" height="50" width="30"></a-plane>
  <a-plane class="menu-pane" position="-50 0 -40" opacity="0" color="blue" rotation="0 50 0" height="50" width="30"></a-plane>
  <a-animation begin="mobileMenuOpen"  attribute="position" dur="550" fill="both" to="0 0 0"></a-animation>
  <a-animation begin="mobileMenuOpen"  attribute="group-opacity.opacity"  dur="550" fill="both" to="1"></a-animation>
</a-entity>
```

Position *does* cascade from the parent to the children, so there's no need for a workaround on that property.

---

*Edit: Ok, I think the above should work, but there are some errors showing up that don't make much sense. Could be my code, or something about the animation wiring. Anyway, hardcoding your animations might be the best option for the moment, as @ngokevin said. Quick example to get you started:*

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('group-opacity', {
  tick: function (t) {
    var opacity = (Math.sin(t / 1000) + 1) / 2;
    this.el.object3D.traverse(function (o) {
      if (o.material) {
        o.material.opacity = opacity;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Note that you don't need `<a-animation/>` at all in this case.

Comment: Getting the following error: 

`aframe.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'schema' of undefined`

Comment: Will debug more after work but it's possible the `<a-animation/>` element needs to reference `group-opacity.opacity` instead of `groupOpacity.opacity`.

Answer (score 2):

I plan on making an animation component that can be mixed into entities.

But for now, you have to do things a bit more manually. That means either using tween.js directly (https://github.com/tweenjs/) with AFRAME.TWEEN, or copy and pasting the animations and making handling that events are fired on all of the entities.

Answer (score -1):

[You can with D3!](http://codepen.io/bryik/pen/yJpEjk)

The position of the menu-panes are relative to the parent entity, so moving the parent moves all the children as well. This part is simple.

The opacity of all the menu-panes can be animated concisely using D3's "selectAll":

```
  // Increase opacity for all menu-panes individually
  var menuPanes = d3.selectAll('.menu-pane');
  menuPanes.transition()
           .duration(1000)
           .attr('opacity', '1');
```

Check the link above for the full example. It shows how to select the parent UI element, attach the custom 'mobileMenuOpen' event, setup the transition function, and trigger the custom event.